# Inserted Binary GUID Value Returned as Function Definition

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model that uses mysql functions to create guid such as:

```
guid: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING.BINARY,
    defaultValue: sequelize.fn('UuidToBin', sequelize.fn('uuid')),
    primaryKey: true
},
inProcess: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, 
...
```

I successfully create new records including a binary guid using the create method,

```
MessagesDBModel.create(messageObj)
        .then((savedMessage) => res.send(200, {
            status: 200,
            message: "OK",
            guid: savedMessage.guid.toString('hex') //outputs [object Object]
```

But, the value of guid cannot be retrieved from the savedMessage object. When I set a breakpoint, savedMessage.dataValues.guid = Fn.

How can I access the inserted value of guid instead of the function that created it?

Comment: Does the create method return a savedMessage object? guid seems to be just a schema so when you use the create method, there should be an object that should be initialized to the schema like var guidSchema = new mongoose.Schema(GuidSchema);. In mongoose, I would do it as var someObj=new guidSchema(parameters);
and the create method should return someObj;

Comment: The create method does return a savedMessage object. All the expected values are present in the object except for the guid element. Note that the guid element is the name of my primary key which is of type Binary(16). Instead of returning the create method value that was inserted successfully, it returns the attributes of the function that created it at run time.

Comment: [object object] is returned usually when the deserialization didn't happen so json.stringify may help instead of .toString but I am just giving you a wild guess as I have no means to test your code.

Comment: I used json.stringify which will perhaps help clarify that problem I am describing.
JSON.stringify(savedMessage.guid)  outputs 
{\"fn\":\"UuidToBin\",\"args\":[{\"fn\":\"uuid\",\"args\":[]}]}
which is the original issue. A reference to the function which created the value for table column named 'guid' is returned instead of the value that was successfully inserted.

Comment: Ok, so I checked the sequelize docs and the first line in the docs suggests that you are accessing the metadata. How, can only be determined if you share your code to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it in the case of `build` first. In the code below

```
const record = Model.build({}) // assuming Model has guid attribute that you wrote
```

What should be `record.guid` at this point? Since the transaction has not yet occurred, the function should not be executed and therefore the `guid` value can not be determined.

This is not a problem for scalar values ​​that have the same value before and after the transaction completes. However, in the case of function, since the point at which the value is determined is the point at which the transaction is committed, `sequelize` has to replace the values ​​of entire objects included in the transaction with the execution result of the function. It seems to be a very hard work.

Currently, it seems like a good way to select again with last_inserted_id or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different approach. I created a stored procedure. Within the procedure declared @guid using the MySQL function. Inserted to all the appropriate tables, then selected back the @guid value for further use in the application.